# Error installing pillow scoped to an AWS EMR Notebook

Tags: amazon-emr

I'm trying to install the `pillow` package scoped to an AWS EMR Notebook.

When I run the following within a Notebook,

```
sc.install_pypi_package("pillow")
```

I get a long error (below).  Apparently, the process is failing to build `pillow` from source.

I can successfully install `pandas` and `celery`.

My cluster is running with the following:  EMR version 6.5.0, with JupyterEnterpriseGateway 2.1.0, TensorFlow 2.4.1, Spark 3.1.2, Livy 0.7.1.

***My question:  How can I install `pillow` on my cluster so I can use it in my notebook?***

*Detailed Error:*

```
Collecting pillow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/83/090146d7871d90a2643d469c319c1d014e41b315ab5cf0f8b4b6a764ef31/Pillow-9.1.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: unknown, unknown
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for unknown: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for unknown: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /tmp/1649603768116-0/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp6ofjlogzpip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FitsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
  running egg_info
  creating src/UNKNOWN.egg-info
  writing src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file 'src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
  
  reading manifest file 'src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  writing manifest file 'src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py", line 996, in <module>
      zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/1649603768116-0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/1649603768116-0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 75, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py", line 804, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py", line 1009, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for unknown
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for unknown: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for unknown: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /tmp/1649603768116-0/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmprbtiizu2pip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
<omitted "copying" output -- appears to be the same as above>
  running egg_info
  writing src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/top_level.txt
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
  
  reading manifest file 'src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  writing manifest file 'src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py", line 996, in <module>
      zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/1649603768116-0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/1649603768116-0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 75, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py", line 804, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py", line 1009, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
  
  The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
  
  
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for unknown
Failed to build unknown unknown
Installing collected packages: unknown
  Running setup.py install for unknown: started
    Running setup.py install for unknown: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /tmp/1649603768116-0/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-_werf9z_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /tmp/1649603768116-0/include/site/python3.7/unknown:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
<omitted "copying" output -- appears to be the same as above>
    running egg_info
    writing src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/top_level.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
    
    reading manifest file 'src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src/UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py", line 996, in <module>
        zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/1649603768116-0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 556, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/1649603768116-0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 75, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py", line 804, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py", line 1009, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    
    
    ----------------------------------------

  Running setup.py (path:/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package pillow produced metadata for project name unknown. Fix your #egg=pillow fragments.
  Failed building wheel for unknown
  Failed building wheel for unknown
Command "/tmp/1649603768116-0/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-_werf9z_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /tmp/1649603768116-0/include/site/python3.7/unknown" failed with error code 1 in /mnt/tmp/pip-build-g56jqdny/pillow/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: user3188040, no, I never found a solution.  I worked around it by installing ```pillow``` using a bootstrap script at cluster creation.  Here's the script:  https://github.com/mherzog01/big_data_demo/blob/main/pip_installs.sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the pip package to the latest version (it's suggested in the warning msg from any successfully installed ones). The following attempt helped resolve my installation issue (as of May 2023).

```
sc.install_pypi_package("pip==23.1.2") # as of May 2023
sc.install_pypi_package("pillow") # if you ultimately want matplotlib, you can skip this line and go for the next
sc.install_pypi_package("matplotlib", "https://pypi.org/simple") #Install matplotlib from given PyPI repository
```